# How to redefine tmux modifier chords to RightAlt + hyphen?

Tags: tmux

By `tmux modifier chords` (in the title) I mean the default combination of keys to make `tmux` listen for an order.
The default chords is `ctrl+b` but because most of the actions I use are `d` and `c` I thought using RightAlt + hyphen (right hand) would be easier to use with the left hand sending commands.
Is it possible? if yes, how?
And do you think it is a good chords (won't it mess with other default chords in an average terminal?)

(Sorry, If I am not using the right vocab I am not an English speaker, please correct my post and delete this message if it can help for being more clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible, but most terminals do not distinguish between LeftAlt and RightAlt – both cause the same type of key sequence to be sent.

Holding Alt typically prefixes the key with an ESC (unless there's some other specific sequence to use), so Alt-hyphen is `ESC -` or `^[-` or `\e-` or `M--` or `Meta--` depending on program. tmux uses emacs-style syntax:

```
set -g prefix M--
```